# Passing a related third class from third SQL Table into a view with a ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am working on poll app in ASP.NET MVC5. I have three SQL tables for their related classes (Poll, PollOption, Vote). Each Poll has an ID, Each PollOption has an ID, and also a Foreign Key to match to the PollID, and each Vote has an ID, and a foreign key to match both the PollOptionID and PollID.

I've created a ViewModel and am successfully pulling the Poll detail view to include a list of the poll options available in that poll. What is the next step in pulling a third table into that view? I'm successfully able to count how many votes exist in that poll within the view, but am struggling linking it to the correct poll option.

I've set up a view model and have passed information in. I'm also using two .Include statements in my controller to capture both polloptions and votes.

Here is my controller action:

```
       public ActionResult DetailsTest(int id)
        {
            var poll = _context.Polls.Include(c => c.PollOptions).Include(c1 => c1.Votes).SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);

            var viewModel = new PollDetailViewModel
            {
                Poll = poll,
            };

            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

and here is my view:

```
@model CamPoll.ViewModels.PollDetailViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Details Test</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("New Poll Option", "New", "PollOptions", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
</p>


<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Poll Option</th>
            <th>Vote </th>
            <th>Vote Count</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>

    @foreach (var pollOption in Model.Poll.PollOptions)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.ActionLink(pollOption.Name, "Details", "PollOptions", new { id = pollOption.Id }, null)</td>

            <td>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Vote</button>
            </td>

            <td>@Model.Poll.Votes.Count()</td>

        </tr>
    }

    </table>
```

There are currently 3 poll options in my example and these are pulling into the table and 2 votes, both which belong to the same poll option. So in my table the line   @Model.Poll.Votes.Count() should pull 2,0,0 for each row of the table. However each row is pulling 2 (which means its counting all votes in that poll, and not all votes in that poll that belong to that polloption)

How do I limit my Votes.Count row to only include those that belong to that specific PollOption and not every vote that belongs to that Poll.

How do I limit my Votes.Count line to only include those that belong to that specific PollOption and not every vote that belongs to that Poll.

Hopefully this makes sense.

Thanks so much for the help.

Edit:

Here are the models:

```
namespace CamPoll.Models
{
    public class Poll
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<PollOption> PollOptions { get; set; }

        public List<Vote> Votes { get; set; }

    }

  public class PollOption
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int PollId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("PollId")]
        public Poll Poll { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; } 

        public int VoteCount { get; set; }

        public List<Vote> Votes { get; set; }

    }

    public class Vote
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public DateTime VoteTime { get; set; }

        public int VoteWorth { get; set; }

        public int PollOptionId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("PollOptionId")]
        public PollOption PollOption { get; set; }

        public int PollId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("PollId")]
        public Poll Poll { get; set; }

    }
}
```

the expected result on the Poll details view is a table that pulls each polloption belonging to that table, and a count of each vote that belongs to each polloption.

Comment: can you describe the modal & properties, what would be the expected result.

Comment: @niravVasoya Hi - I updated the question with models and expected result. Thank you!

Comment: so you basically want the count of votes of a specific poll option?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I'm trying to do. I'm able to count total votes in each poll, but I'm having trouble getting it to count just the votes that belong in each poll option @FakharAhmadRasul

Comment: what is the relation between Poll and PollOptions? is it possible for a Poll to have multiple PollOptions or a Poll can only have one PollOption?

Comment: A poll can have numerous poll options, and then  each poll option can have numerous votes. @FakharAhmadRasul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a `PollOptionsViewModel`

```
public class PollOptionsViewModel
{
    public int PollOptionsId { get; set; }
    public int VoteCount { get; set; }
    //other properties
}
```

in your `PollDetailViewModel` add a list of `PollOptionsViewModel` then in your controller make the following changes:-

```
public ActionResult DetailsTest(int id)
{
    var poll = _context.Polls.Include(c => c.PollOptions).Include(c1 => c1.Votes).SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);

    List<PollOptionsViewModel> pollOptionsList = new List<PollOptionsViewModel>();

    var viewModel = new PollDetailViewModel
    {
        Poll = poll,
    };
    foreach(var pollOption in poll.PollOptions)
    {
        PollOptionsViewModel pollOptionsViewModel = new PollDetailViewModel
        {
            PollOptionsId = pollOption.PollOptionsId,
            VoteCount = pollOption.Votes.Count
        };
        pollOptionsList.Add(pollOptionsViewModel);
    }
    viewModel.PollOptionsViewModelList = pollOptionsList;

    return View(viewModel);
}
```